# Do Python lists not have a len attribute?

Tags: python

The output of the following script:

```
a = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']

print len(a)
print hasattr(a,"len")
```

is

```
4
False
```

I was expecting the `False` to be `True`, especially since `len()` works on `a`.  Am I missing something about what an attribute actually is?

Comment: I think you are missing something, yes.  Why do you think calling `len(a)` would be related to `a` having an attribute called `len`?  (There is a magic method called `__len__`, but that is neither here nor there as far as your question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're missing something. [`len(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) returns [`x.__len__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__), not `x.len`.

Try running [`dir(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) to see what attributes are available on an object.

Comment: not quite, `len(x)` returns `x.__len__()` assuming the method exists and returns a valid integer length.